# dashed nodes html-like labels graphviz

Tags: html, graphviz, dot

I have a dot graph with html-like label nodes and I am trying to have as node's appearance for some of them "dotted" and "dashed".

I know it is possible to modify the appearance of a polygon-based or record-based shape using the style attribute, for example style = dotted or style = dashed.

How can I do the same for the html-like label?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/node-shapes#html) has a grammar for the supported subset of HTML. It doesn't contain anything that would allow dashing.

But since they are HTML-like *labels* you can just use a regular polygon-based node around the label, and dash it like you always have.

Comment: Thanks, this was actually the solution I needed. I used the polygon-based node with shape = box and style = dotted or dashed and the HTML-like labels with tables and border = 0. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html) mentions the `style` attribute of `TABLE` and `TD` nodes. It claims the only supported styles are `rounded` and `radial`, but in fact it **also** supports `dashed` and `dotted`:

[image: table with partially dotted cell border]

```
graph G {
  node [shape=plaintext];
  block [label=<
  <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="4">
    <TR>
      <TD COLSPAN="2" SIDES="LR" STYLE="dotted" HEIGHT="20" WIDTH="200"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD COLSPAN="2" SIDES="LR" HEIGHT="10" WIDTH="200"></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="100"><I>type</I></TD>
      <TD COLSPAN="1" WIDTH="100"><I>grow</I></TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
      <TD COLSPAN="1"><I>length</I></TD>
      <TD COLSPAN="1"><I>gc</I></TD>
    </TR>
  </TABLE>>];
}
```